# Having an issue passing an array to a Function as only first word is printed c++

Tags: c++

I am new to passing values to functions, please guide me what I am doing wrong here, thanks!

> The question: Write a C++ program in which, read a c-string sentence
> one by one from a file “sentence .txt”. Now your task is to break each
> word of sentence into another c-string word, now write that word into
> a file “word.txt”. Note : You must create atleast 1 function to
> separate the words from sentence, you cannot use strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;



char sentence2word(char array[100])
{
    ofstream fout2;
    fout2.open("word.txt");

        fout2 << array << endl;

        return array[100];
}
int main()
{

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("sentence.txt");

    char array[100];
    fin >> array;
    cout << "Output successful!";

    sentence2word(array);

    return 0;
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: There are some more beginner mistakes in this (for example any code after a return statement will not be executed), but for now I recommend reading about for-loops and arrays.

Comment: According to the instructions, you should read one whole *sentence* at a time, and separate each sentence into words. You're reading one word, which you then output. The problem is not with passing the array, it's that you haven't understood what `>>` does, which you would have noticed if you had printed the input immediately after reading it.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free help desk. People answer not only to help you, but to help anyone who might have the same issue in the future. As such, do not remove (or edit out in that case) your question once you have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program show how to get started with reading and writing from/into text files in C++. This is just to get you started and in practice i  use std::string and std::istringstream to do this but in your note it is written that we cannot use strings so i did not use std::string. The program reads line by line from an input.txt file and write word by word into an output.txt file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>//needed to read/write files
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS 500
using namespace std;


//function that writes lines word by word into output.txt 
void writeWordByWord(std::ofstream &m_outFile, char (&lineArg)[MAX_NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS])
{ int i = 0;
 while(lineArg[i] != '\0')
 {
     if(lineArg[i] != ' ')
     {m_outFile << lineArg[i];
     //std::cout<< lineArg[i]<<" wrote"<<std::endl;
     ++i;
     }
     else{
         m_outFile << '\n';
         ++i;
     }
 }
 
 //m_outFile << '\n';
}
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   char line[MAX_NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS];
   
   std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
   std::ofstream outFile("output.txt");
   
   while(inFile.getline(line, MAX_NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS, '\n'))
   {
        std::cout<<line<<std::endl; 
        writeWordByWord(outFile, line);
        
   }
   inFile.close();
   outFile.close();
   
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, this is actually much more easier, thanks for the explanation and thanks!